# How to bundle JRE with application?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Due to the fact Oracle dropping JavaFX form JDK 11 on there will be the need to bundle a JavaFX supporting JRE with any application which uses JavaFX based UIs.

Is there an officially way to bundle JRE with an application? Is there a distributable version of the JDK or only "hacks" to do that?

Comment: In NetBeans you can use "Package As" to create a distribution that includes a JRE. With Java 9 you can use `jlink` to create a package that includes a JRE.

Comment: not yet decided - see discussion on jfx mailinglist: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-March/021624.html ... or maybe misunderstanding your question, seeing horse' comment ... anyway, interesting read on the mailinglist :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If I go with Java 9 JavaFX is supported for an even shorter periode of time than with Java 8 as far as I understand Oracle's roadmap.

Comment: @kleopatra As far as I can tell from Oracle's official statements it is decided that JDK 11 won't contain JavaFX and that JavaFX has to be installed speperatly.

Comment: `jlink` is also available in Java 10

Comment: If JavaFX will be available as an external dependency, as mentioned in the mailing list kleopatra linked, there won't be any need to package the entire jre with the app.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Where, in NetBeans 8, is "Package as".  I can't find it.